# Google denied update due Remediation for Implicit PendingIntent Vulnerability for HMS

Tags: android, security, google-play-console, android-pendingintent, huawei-mobile-services

When i'm trying to update my app - i got error during review process. Remediation for Implicit PendingIntent Vulnerability - https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/10437428. I just changed one method. Security vulnerabilities as follows:

Implicit PendingIntent => com.huawei.hms.push.o.a

In my gradle:

```
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:location:5.0.0.302'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:maps:5.0.2.300'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:5.0.3.300'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:push:5.3.0.304'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to upgrade the Push SDK to the [latest version](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-app-version-0000001074227861#section3358144513280) may solve this issue.

Currently, the latest Push SDK version for Android is `com.huawei.hms:push:6.3.0.304`.